# YACC Not getting the values from successor nodes

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I'm making a school project and I'm having some trouble.

I have this yacc grammer

```
FILE        : '{' GEOMETRY '}'
            ;

GEOMETRY    : key_type ':' value_point ',' key_coordinates ':' PONTO
            ;


PONTO       : VETOR_MIN2 { printf("%s", $<str>1); }
            ;

VETOR_MIN2  : '['  numero ',' numero ']'
            ;
```

When I make that printf in the non terminal PONTO I only get this: **[**

but I should get something like this: **[20, 10]**
What it's missing here? Please help.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semantic value of a rule is the value that resides in `$$` after that rule's actions have been run. If a rule does not have any actions (as is the case for `VECTOR_MIN2`), the default action is `$$ = $1;` (unless there is no `$1` or the types don't match, in which case there is no default action).

If you want `VECTOR_MIN2` to produce a different value, you'll need to add an action and assign a different value to `$$`.

Comment: ..., for example `$$= $2`

Comment: so should I do comething like `$<str>$=$<str>2;`? in my VECTOR_MIN2´ if I want for example the number(terminal)? or could I join all the strings as well?

Comment: @Rafael That would give you "20" as the result instead of "[". If you want "[20, 10]" you will indeed have to concatenate the various strings, using `sprintf` for example. Note that you'll have to take care of allocating (and eventually freeing) the memory for that yourself. PS: I recommend that you use `%type` declarations, so you don't have to write `<str>` everywhere.

Comment: @sepp2k I written this: `{ sprintf($<str>$, "%s%s%s%s%s", $<str>1,$<str>2,$<str>3,$<str>4,$<str>5); }` and it's working fine :) but, I have this warning: `warning: ‘%s’ directive writing up to 99 bytes into a region of size between 1 and 100 [-Wformat-overflow=] VETOR_MIN2 : '['  numero ',' numero ']' { sprintf($<str>$, "%s%s%s%s%s", $<str>1,$<str>2,$<str>3,$<str>4,$<str>5); }` How could I free memory? and Im using the `%type` in the terminals, it is possivel to that to the non terminals as well?

Comment: @Rafael I'd just go with `sprintf($$, "[%s, %s]", $2, $4)` for readability, but that's fine. And yes, `%type` works for non-terminals, too (in fact that's what it's primarily used for - for terminals you can just supply the type with the `%token` directive). What's the type of `str`? If it's `char*`, you'll first need to make it point somewhere (and make sure that that somewhere is large enough) before you write into it with `sprintf`. If it's something like `char str[42]`, you should make sure that you're not writing more than 42 characters (or whatever the actual size is) to it.

Comment: @sepp2k my type is char str[50]